# Apache crash on launch - W2008 Server

Tags: xampp, apache

I installed Xampp on my Windows Server 2008. It worked fine, untill I decided to install some updates.
Now Apache doesn't start any more and I get these errors;

```
[Wed Aug 29 23:31:20.328125 2012] [core:warn] [pid 1540:tid 312] AH00098: pid file
C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Aug 29 23:31:20.968750 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 1540:tid 312] AH01873: Init:Session        Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
```

I'm trying to install Cacti on the server to monitor everything... Don't think it's relevant, but just saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need it:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#post_234
Apache 2.4 will not start with added SSL support on windows until additional module (compare to Apache 2.2 configuration) was enabled: socache_shmcb_module

This additional info is at the beginning of the httpd-ssl.conf, but it takes time to read it :)

```
# Required modules: mod_log_config, mod_setenvif, mod_ssl, socache_shmcb_module (for default value of SSLSessionCache)
```